# Can OS X 10.6.8 Snow Leopard be installed on a 2007 MacBook Intel Core 2 Duo, 1GB

Tags: macbook-pro, itunes, snow-leopard

Ok so i have a 2007 MacBook2,1 - 2.16 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo - OS X 10.5.8 - Memory 1GB 667 MHz DDR2 SDRAM.

I can't currently sync my iphone 4s (IOS 7.1.1) or ipad (IOS 8.2) because i can't upgrade to itunes 11 which i need IOS 10.6.8.

with my macbook can i upgrade to snow leopard 10.6 then to 10.6.8 ??

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am running SNL 10.6.8 on a similar 2007 MBP, a little faster than yours (2.6 GHZ).  Original OS was Tiger.  I had initially upgraded to Lion but found it wouldn't run Final Cut Express 4.0 reliably.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

According to [Everymac](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook/specs/macbook-core-2-duo-2.0-white-13-mid-2007-specs.html) the Macbook 2,1 can be updated as far as Lion 10.7.5, so yes, you should be fine on 10.6.8